# How can I make a div's border fill the parent div's height?

Tags: css

My border for a div only displays a border for the height of the content in it. How can I make the border fill everything?

Screenshot:

[image: div]
.

I have border-right set in the left div. For the first div, the height is only one line long, and this means the border is only 1 line long. (Another div not in the screenshot to the left expands that div to the current size, which is greater than the border-creating div.

I have tried setting height:100% however since I am using `float:left` on everything it doesn't seem to have any effect.

**EDIT**: Short JSFiddle on the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/KvS8w/

Comment: An example of your code would be helpful. I had no problem using height: 100%; paired with float: left; to fill the parent div in a quick test.

Comment: Hi Parker Young, please see the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KvS8w/

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Why dont you use a css framework. There are also nice video tutorials for them on youtube and so on.

If you just want to you css, I recommend a css framework like 960 or others.. ;)

regards, dave

Answer (score 0):

So I misunderstood your question last night.
Also you jsfiddle helped a lot in understanding what was your exact situation.

The thing is, when you set the height of a component to 100% it takes the height of it's parent container, if it's still a relative value, it goes up the DOM tree until it finds a fixed value.

So, you could either give your main DIV a fixed height (that could cause some overflow), or add some javascript styling transformation that will calculate it's height based on it's tallest child.

Edit :

Here is a simple Javascript solution

```
var divh = document.getElements('.reply');
var i = 0;
for ( i = 0 ; i < divh.length; i++ )
{
        divh[i].style.height = divh[i].offsetHeight +'px';
}
```

You can see it in action in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KvS8w/42/) based on yours.

Comment: I don't want to set a fixed height for my div - it's not possible to do something like this with just css?

Comment: Not so much for pure CSS styling, but like I said, you can use javascript to do the job for you, this way it can size up your stuff pretty neatly.